# Django - Get the first attribute from all objects in a Model

Tags: django, list, object, django-models, model

I am trying to get a list of the content of one attribute from all objects in a model.

For now, I am doing this:

```
titles_list = []
for item in  A.objects.all(): 
   titles_list.append(item.title)

print titles_list
```

Is there a more interesting solution based on a memory / time economy to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The same can be implemented in one line using [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) with `flat=True`:

```
print A.objects.values_list('title', flat=True)
```

Comment: +1 . Just a side note, This would return `ValuesListQuerySet` object, which is fine for most cases. But if you need a python object list, just cast it to a list type `list()`. Also, `.all()` is redundant here.

Comment: Edited and removed redundant `all()`